# How to resolve generic type in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to resolve generic type trough Unity, but I'm getting error: {"The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)":null}.

My code and configuration is as follow:

```
namespace Prj.Common.Workflow
{
    public class ServiceActivityBase<I, O> : CodeActivity, IServiceActivityBase   
    {
    }
}

namespace Prj.Services
{
    public sealed class TestActivity : ServiceActivityBase<InputDto, OutputDto>
    {
    }
}

namespace Prj.Dto
{
    public class InputDto {}
    public class OutputDto {}
}
```

Each namespaces is placed in the separate asssembly with the same name as the namespace. I have a following registration in web.config:

```
<register   type="Prj.Common.Workflow.ServiceActivityBase'2[[Prj.Dto.DajDetailDietetickejPotravinyVstupDto,Prj.Dto],[Prj.Dto.DajDetailDietetickejPotravinyVystupDto,Prj.Dto]], Prj.Common.Workflow"
mapTo="Prj.Services.TestActivity, Prj.Services"
name="TestActivity"
>
<constructor/>
<interceptor type="VirtualMethodInterceptor"/>
<policyInjection />
</register>
```

I'm receiving error while loading configuration:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
```

Can somebody help?

thanks

Comment: Would this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/07/25/working-with-generic-types-in-unity-configuration-section.aspx help?

Comment: For a complete worked example of auto-registration in Unity v3.5, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168458/unity-autoregistration-convention-based-registration-unity/25654904#25654904

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering the dependency in code? This might help you narrow down issue. Registration should look like this: `container.RegisterType<ServiceActivityBase<InputDto,OutputDto>,TestActivity>()`. This way you would know if your issue is only in your XML file.