# Unity.AutoRegistration ?? Convention Based Registration Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, design-patterns

My code is as follows

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer(); 

container
.ConfigureAutoRegistration()
.LoadAssemblyFrom(typeof(Test).Assembly.Location)
.LoadAssemblyFrom(typeof(ITest).Assembly.Location)
.ApplyAutoRegistration();
```

This is my first question.

I'm not sure whether I have used the LoadAssemblyFrom method correctly here:

```
ITest test = container.Resolve<ITest>();
```

When I try to compile I get the exception "ResolutionFailedException".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that what you are looking for is this:

```
container.ConfigureAutoRegistration()
         .LoadAssemblyFrom(typeof(ITest).Assembly.Location)
         .LoadAssemblyFrom(typeof(Test).Assembly.Location)
         .Include(If.ImplementsITypeName, Then.Register())
         .ApplyAutoRegistration();
```

This will tell Unity.AutoRegistration to register all types where there is an interface with the same name, prefixed with I.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working console example showing how to set Unity up for registration by convention, then transfer control into the dependency injection world. You will have to add the `Unity` NuGet package for this to work.

Tested with Unity v3.5 and VS 2012.

```
#region
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

#endregion

namespace Demo___Unity
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var container = new UnityContainer())
            {
                // Manual method.
                //container.RegisterType<IEntryPoint, EntryPoint>();
                //container.RegisterType<IInjected, Injected>();

                // Set up registration by convention.
                // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention.aspx
                container.RegisterTypes(
                    AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(),
                    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                    WithName.Default,
                    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);

                var controller = container.Resolve<IEntryPoint>();
                controller.Main();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IEntryPoint
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        void Main();
    }

    public class EntryPoint : IEntryPoint
    {
        private readonly IInjected Injected;

        public EntryPoint(IInjected injected)
        {
            Injected = injected;
        }

        public void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Hello, world!\n");
            Injected.SubMain();
            Injected2.SubMain();
            Console.Write("[any key to continue]");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Demonstrates property injection.
        [Dependency]
        public IInjected Injected2 { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IInjected
    {
        void SubMain();
    }

    public class Injected : IInjected
    {
        public void SubMain()
        {
            Console.Write("Hello, sub world!\n");
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```